# error handling with firebase nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following in index.js:

```
router.post('/signup', function(err, req, res, next){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var fname = req.body.fname;
    var lname = req.body.lname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    database.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, username, fname, lname);
    //This is causing redirect to 404 page. Want to just stay here. 
    if (err){
      alert('Email has already been registered');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }

});
```

I have another module where I am doing the user authentication using firebase.

database.js

```
exports.createUserWithEmailAndPassword = function(email, password, username, fname, lname){
  if (!email || !password || !username || !fname || !lname){
    console.log ('email: ' +  email);
    console.log ('password: ' +  password);
    console.log ('username: ' +  username);
    console.log ('fname: ' +  fname);
    console.log ('lname: ' +  lname);
    throw Error('You are missing information');
  }
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + username).set({
      email: email,
      fname : fname,
      lname : lname
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    console.log('ERROR CODE: ' + errorCode);
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log('ERROR MESSAGE' + errorMessage);
    throw Error('Unable to save user.')
  });
};
```

User authentication works. My question is more to do with the error handling. Right now, in index.js when I run into an error the app goes to the 404 not found page. Ideally, I'd like to just stay on the same page, and display and error message on the view somewhere.

What should I be doing differently in order to prevent the redirect to the 404 page? I think it has something to do with the err being passed in the function based on [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) express documentation.

Comment: That code segment isn't actually redirecting to a 404... you would be looking for a `res.status(404)` or `res.redirect('/your404page.html')` or something like that.

Comment: sure in my app.js I have a bit of code that redirects in an event of an error to my own custom 404 error page. What I want to know is the proper way of handling the error so that I DONT go to that page. I'd liek to stay on the signup page in the event of an error.

Comment: Perhaps it's the `throw Error()` in database.js that's causing that to happen then?

Comment: Have you actually experienced an error? or is it just trying to redirect to `/` and giving you a 404.